# How could I not include all the css and js files in every page in rails 4.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a newbie. Here's my problem. I just found that all css and js files generated by rails under app/assets are included in every page. I was considering how I could separate them into local ones(just for this page), and global ones(for all pages).
For example, I would like to put jquery.js in all my pages. But for 3DHelper.js, I hope it only appear in specific pages.
Are there any good ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assets pipeline gives you a good improvements in performance when you avoid using separate css/js files in your APP. And it is strongly recommended to follow this way!

If you would like some js file is executed only on some pages you can do the following:

add controller/action names to `data` or `class` attribute to body (in layout)

```
<body data-controller="<%= controller.controller_name %>" data-action="<%= controller.action_name %>">
```

add if condition to your js file which should be executed only on specific page. Something like this

```
if (($('body').data('controller') == 'YourSpecificController') && ($('body').data('action') == 'YourSpecificAction'))
```

Comment: Sorry for being so late. Your answer works like a charm! I think this is the most beautiful approach yet. And by the way, since all js files are put into one single file, it's better to put every js file into a unnamed function space rather than using local variables. Thanks for your answer.